# What hardware did advanced programming languages run on?

Tags: history

Some years ago, I discovered an obscure programming language called Haskell. This language is mind-blowingly powerful; I can barely believe it even exists. But what's even more shocking is, it was apparently invented in 1990.

Not only that, but it's based on an even older language called Miranda, which apparently dates to 1985. And that in turn is based on something called ML, which goes all the way back to 1973.

Like most people, I spent most of the 1980s learning to use BASIC on an 8-bit home microcomputer. I spent many, *many* sleepless nights typing in code that would just barely make the machine do something interesting.

It *boggles my mind* that decades before that, a bunch of greybeards locked away in a secret buncker somewhere were designing these insanely powerful programming languages.

I have to ask... in 1973, what sort of *hypothetical future computer* would have actually been able to *run* something this powerful?

Comment: LISP was invented in 1958 …

Comment: Some of the early languages were quite powerful. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages).  Particularly influential in later languages was Smalltalk.  These ran on mainframes and timesharing machines, more powerful than micros, but less than supercomputers.

Comment: [Refal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refal) is even older; its runtime engine is very small, and it was used on mainframes with as little as a few dozen Kb of RAM accessible to a user process. No magic there.

Comment: BTW, many features of Haskell (type inference, type classes, monads) have made their way into modern widely-used programming languages under different names (E.g., async/await is a typical example for a monad).

Comment: And besides Lisp, we have APL in 1966, Smalltalk in 1972, Prolog in 1972, and they all ran on existing machines, not on future hypothetical computers.

Comment: "*It is practically impossible to teach good programming to students that have had a prior exposure to BASIC: as potential programmers they are mentally mutilated beyond hope of regeneration.*" —  [Edsger W. Dijkstra (Author of A Discipline of Programming, 1976)](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/1013817.Edsger_W_Dijkstra)

Comment: @RayButterworth - "I got better". (Monty Python, the Holy Grail)

Comment: The notion that a more expressive programming language necessarily requires more computing resources to run the compiled code seems like a fallacy, but none of the answerers have mentioned it, so I have abstained from answering for now. In my opinion however the premise of the question should be challenged

Comment: Those old greybeards had access to computers with one to two orders of magnitude more main memory, speed, and data storage than the 70's era, 8-bit hobby computers. (Don't ask me how I know!)

Comment: Are you sure all the features that impress you were in the languages from the start?

Comment: @TomW: I don't see any indication in the question that the OP thinks the machine code generated by a Haskell compiler is more resource-intensive than that generated by a BASIC compiler. Rather, the notion seems to be that a Haskell implementation (be it compiler or interpreter) would require more resources than a BASIC implementation (ditto). And, I think that that notion is actually *correct* (though I could be wrong).

Comment: @J.G. That's a very good point. I've never actually seen Miranda or ML. However, the Wikipedia article seems to indicate that ML had at least *some* of the amazing stuff. (Garbage collection, automatic type inferrence, pattern matching...)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I can't guarantee [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)#History) details will address when Haskell started to become amazing, but a lot of languages were much, much less capable in their early years, or even early decades. It's a shame there aren't more language-specific books like [*C# in Depth*](https://amazon.co.uk/dp/1617294535) to show the feature history.

Comment: @TomW I guess it's more that, in a world where BASIC is the only programming language, I'm amazed that somebody came up with something so much more powerful...

Comment: Your premise of a world where 'BASIC is the only programming language' is flawed - BASIC was a relatively late arrival (1964) *and* was intentionally simplified for (as the name says) Beginners.  People designing new languages in academia did not have viewpoints constrained by BASIC.

Comment: Since when is Haskell considered "obscure"? Its probably considered *the* most typical functional programming language and is used widely when discussing functional programming. It had tremendous influence on later programming languages and still is a great language. Basically everyone who has at least some formal programming education will at some point learn about it.

Comment: Note that all of these various languages usually compile down to machine code.  Just like any other language.    I like Haskell too - that was just one of the amazing language paradigms you get introduced to at the university level.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Miranda was quite similar to Haskell.

Comment: @Polygnome: that was my instinctive reaction, too. While Haskell is definitely not mainstream, it is far from obscure. It has overtaken ML / OCaml as the standard / canonical / prototypical example of typed functional programming, and is the most widely-used language of that particular branch of programming. (Technically, Scala has more users, but it is usually considered "object-functional" or "post-functional".) And it is a very successful language, at least considered by the standards of evolution (spreading your genome): Java's Generics are based on Haskell, C# and Scala have monad ...

Comment: … comprehension syntax, advanced typesystem features such as typeclasses are becoming mainstream, a principled approach to program structuring based on Category Theory is becoming mainstream (there are "Typeclassopedia"-style libraries for Scala, Java, C#, ECMAScript, ...)

Comment: BASIC came with early home computers, decades before then when digital computing was new more complicated languages existed.  It is a case of how much storage and processing power you have to implement a compiler and how much does it take to create a compiler and market it, etc.  You already dumped the equivalent of most of the price of a new car into that computer now you want to buy a compiler plus ram if available for the price of say an engine or transmission.

Comment: while being decades old it really needed the home/business computer explosion to really generate a market for languages, BASIC helped greatly to get those computers sold, but the market was needed to take decades old languages, turn those into mature products, eventually enough ram and processing power to optimize (would take 5-10 additional minutes to build our small application with optimizations turned on).  And then more years to really create the opportunity for free tools.

Comment: Look at what folks are able to do today with modern tools on retro platforms like the atari 2600, amigas, commodore 64s, etc.  It was the rare developer that had the computer to do such things and they would almost have had to create such tools for themselves, so it didnt happen until later.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

8-bit home micros were not powerful computers when they first appeared. They were inexpensive enough that individuals could buy them, and almost everything else took second place to price.

In 1973, there were early versions of UNIX running on DEC PDP-11 machines, and a wide variety of 24-bit to 36-bit machines with proprietary operating systems. None of them had GUIs, which soak up a lot of the power of modern computers. They could definitely run an ML implementation; you might not be able to handle such big problems as on a modern machine, and it would certainly be slower, but it would *work*. The difference was the price: something in the region of $50,000, rather than $500 or less for a home computer in the next decade.

As an example, the original ML implementation was written in LISP on a DEC [PDP-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10), a 36-bit machine often used for multi-user systems, such as universities. This was a big machine, costing $500,000 or more for a complete installation, but widely capable by the standards of the time.

Comment: For reference, [the first ML interpreter was written in Lisp on a PDP-10 at Edinburgh University](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/archive/mjcg/papers/HolHistory.html).

Comment: People have a mistaken impression that "non-micro" computers were big and slow compared to microcomputers.  Big, yes, but slow, not so much.  It wasn't until Intel's 80486 that microcomputers started offering performance even remotely competitive with that of "real" computers.  What made microcomputers revolutionary was their size and price.  For mathematical computations, even the 1960s computers that went to the Moon were faster than commonplace desktop machine a decade later (though its RAM capacity was a limited to minimize weight).

Comment: @supercat I'm dubious about your statement "*Big, yes, but slow, not so much. It wasn't until Intel's 80486 that microcomputers started offering performance even remotely competitive with that of "real" computers.*"  Micro CPUs starting with the 8088/8087 were **very** fast compared to mini- and mainframe computers **on computationally expensive operations**.  It was (and still is, for mainframes) IO operations which ate micros for lunch.  For example, an IBM 4341 with 6MB RAM and 1.5 MIPS could easily support 70 simultaneous interactive database users.

Comment: @RonJohn, I don't know. I was employed by a university computer science department when the original IBM-PC hit the market, and I don't remember anybody rushing to buy them for scientific or engineering number crunching. But maybe that too was because of I/O: As fashion accessories, 9-track tapes made you look like way more of a serious player than 5 1/4 inch floppies ever could do.

Comment: As somebody who grew up in the 1980s, I watched "computers" go from lumbering 8-bit things to the current 64-bit multi-core beasts we have today. I guess I'm not really aware that "other" computer systems existed, somewhere hidden from view...

Comment: It's very hard to compare performance of a generic machine to one that is built to a strict application requirement, the Apollo computers were precisely as powerful as they needed to be.

Comment: @RonJohn: The AGC could perform 15x15 multiplies faster than something like a Commodore PET, even though the latter was faster for addition and subtraction.  While the 8088 could outperform the AGC, so could many machines of the AGC's era.  The goal of the AGC was to be powerful enough to perform the tasks necessary for the Moon landing.  I think it was less powerful than the computers in the first stage rockets, but it also weighed a lot less since it would need to have a lot more delta-V applied to it.

Comment: Since you mention the PDP’s, I’d like to point readers to [a physical recreation of the PDP11 based on simh and a Raspberry Pi](https://obsolescence.wixsite.com/obsolescence/pidp-11). I have build one and absolutely love to tinker with it. It also runs ML/LISP/... Hardware is not representative, but it gives you a feel of how thangs were done in those days.

Answer (score 11):

I believe those languages were generally developed at universities, which at the time (the mid 1970's to early 90's) typically started the era using home-build systems, eventually moving into minicomputers running VMS or Unix in their CS departments. These systems were typically used because they were relatively cheap. CS departments needed computers, but didn't have mainframe money (unlike these same schools' alumni outreach departments, which brought in money and thus got nice expensive usually-IBM mainframes. But I digress..)

For example, the ultimate grandparent of Haskell was [David Turner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Turner_(computer_scientist))'s research at the University of Kent at Canterbury. His functional language interpreters originally ran on homebrew computers at the department, but were ported to Unix from where they became research languages used by students. It was first monetized as [Miranda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_(programming_language)) on Unix systems.

The first actual Haskell (1.0) compiler was written by [Lennart Augustsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennart_Augustsson) of Chalmers University, on top of his existing LML (Lazy ML) compiler, which appears to have run on Unix. The next two were Yale Haskell, and Gopher, both university-ish projects. Yale Haskell was written in CMU Common Lisp (so Unix). Gopher was a student's fun side project, and actually ran on a 386 PC off a single floppy disk (one assumes under DOS).

If you're interested, Paul Hudak, John Hughes, Simon Peyton Jones, and Philip Wadler have written a great paper on [the history of Haskell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/history.pdf?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2F%7Esimonpj%2Fpapers%2Fhistory-of-haskell%2Fhistory.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Well, those languages were running on real computers. Except that they weren't *microcomputers* but supercomputers (see the works of [Seymour Cray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seymour_Cray)).

Those computers were extremely expensive and had much more memory than the 1980s microcomputers. An individual just couldn't afford it. It was shared between students/researchers. Also had more evolved storage devices, not just standard audio cassettes.

All that allowed to develop and use compiled languages. Note that compiled languages are possible on microcomputers (there are Z80 & 6502 C compilers for instance, even if they are cross-compilers, not native) but the code takes a lot of memory. On a microcomputer, programs are generally BASIC + assembly for memory reasons (assembly being used for speed in game main loops, BASIC being used for menus, score, management, where operations were'nt time-critical).

BASIC is not as advanced as the languages you're mentionning, but it's also extremely cheap memory-wise, with tokens only taking 1 byte of memory, and interpreted by the ROM. It also provided easy access to computer hardware (input, graphics, sound), and all usually fitted in 48+16 Kb RAM. It's really not the same scale as for specialized supercomputers, even if those were older (the cray 1 clock was 80MHz, most home computers clock were a few MHz in comparison)

I was mentionning 6502 and z80 compilers, but those are relatively recent, and only runned from a more powerful machine. A native C compiler (or other language) for a 8-bit home machine (single processor, 64k RAM) is extremely unlikely and would be slow & impractical. Even *assemblers* weren't so common at that time (BBC micro had one, though). People used to enter hex opcode in DATA sections instead...

The first 8-bit microcomputers were just a cut-down, home version of its ancestors, affordable to everyone. Only when the 16/32 bit computers appeared that it became possible to use more evolved languages.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104256/discussion-on-answer-by-jean-francois-fabre-what-hardware-did-advanced-programmi).